# Why does my Google Optimize experiment show no clear winner

Tags: ab-testing, google-optimize, abtest

[image: Google Optimize Results]

I did a very simple text, the footer contact form on the left of the website or the right of the website.  The results showed "no clear winner".  But the below data shows that one has 5 conversions vs 1, which I consider to be significant (albeit low numbers).  It also says there is a 95% probability that this one will be better.

What am I not understanding about this data?  Is it that the numbers are too low in volume to give a reading or is it a bug or is there something I've missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its probably because your AB Test did not have a lot of traffic, in each variant.  So 5 conversions vs 1, is not really a big difference between the two.

Comment: It depends how much a conversion is worth ha ha.  The 5 that converted were a cool billion bitcoin each, the other was just a tenner.  :D  But thanks for the answer, probably the best I'm getting.